# GRUB2 won't boot Windows 10 from second hard drive, but it boots fine directly

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, multi-boot, grub2

I have two hard drives in my laptop - an M.2 SSD (1st) and a Sata 3 SSD (2nd). The 1st one contains fedora linux, and laptop boots from that one. The 2nd one contains Windows 10. I don't use UEFI, but just plain BIOS.

Recently my M.2 drive died, so I had to reinstall linux. Since then, I'm unable to boot Windows 10.

I did some experimenting and found out that if I remove the 1st drive from the laptop, Win 10 boots just fine. I can also boot to linux, and use `qemu-kvm` to boot a virtual machine from `/dev/sdb` and that also works just fine.

The error I'm getting when booting Windows 10 is a Blue Screen with `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`.

My grub2 config is generated by `os-prober`, and looks like the following:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 10 (on /dev/sdb1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-DED8DF58D8DF2D91' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  DED8DF58D8DF2D91
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root DED8DF58D8DF2D91
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
    ntldr /bootmgr
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

Full grub.cfg: https://pastebin.com/DbP8rFC3

For reference, here's my disk layout:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0 489,1G  0 disk 
├─sdb2   8:18   0 299,8G  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0  97,7G  0 part 
└─sdb1   8:17   0   500M  0 part 
sda      8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   200G  0 part /
```

sda is my main, Linux drive. sdb2 is the other SSD drive, with db1 being the 500M Windows system boot partition, sdb2 being my windows data store, and sdb3 is just a linux data partition I use to keep a few virtual machines to save some space.

Here's output from `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="a65aced8-4dd6-410c-b42d-92b5f66fa15e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7a2436a8-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="ZastrzeM-EM-<one przez system" UUID="DED8DF58D8DF2D91" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="7a2436a8-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="7CA0E642A0E6028E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="7a2436a8-02"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="68e2ae68-dfaa-4317-ac95-494917a12543" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7a2436a8-03"
```

What could I be missing in my current grub configuration, that I had on my previous Linux installation?

Answer (score 0):

Why : probally u install linux at same partition with windows.if u want to dual boot u cant install 2 os at same partition

Fix: create second partition and install windows there.then install easybcd program at windows to recreate good grub

Hope it can help anyone

Comment: Unfortunatelly not - like I've wrirten in my first post, I have two hard drives, and both my systems are on separate drives. They are certainly not at the same partition.